# Appending data in R using get_followers function

Tags: r, append, rstudio

I have a list of users in a dataframe. I am trying to find the followers of these users and place them in a single dataframe file. Here is my code:

```
library(rtweet)

#Searching users with a specific tweet.
A <- search_tweets("RT @ReggaeMarleyBob: Sometimes you have no", n=1000)

#Extract the first column
B <- as.data.frame(A[1], drop=FALSE)

# Drop any duplicate user names:
C <- unique(B)

#collecting the followers of users in C
for(i in 1:nrow(C)) {
  print(C[i,1])
  D <- get_followers(C[i,1], n= "all", page = "-1", parse = TRUE, as_double = FALSE, token = NULL)
}
```

Is there a way where I can append the data in C to D?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`get_followers` returns a `data.frame`. You can append to a data frame using `rbind`:

```
D <- c()
for(i in 1:nrow(C)) {
  print(C[i,1])
  D <- rbind(D, get_followers(C[i,1], n= "all", page = "-1", parse = TRUE, as_double = FALSE, token = NULL))
}
```

Comment: Hello, I tested the code on a dataframe of 2 users. These 2 users have a total of 203 followers (combined). The code gave me 18,000 results. What is going on? What is wrong with my code?

Comment: I tested with the first 3 users: OneNaziq, AzimRidzuan_, pais_10, they have 1106, 485 and 597 followers on twitter, respectively, and `nrow(D)` correctly gives `1106 + 485 + 597 = 2188`, so the code seems to work to me

Comment: Can you please share the code, why is it nrow(D) not nrow(C)?

Comment: @HussainShehadeh I changed the loop statement to `i in 1:3` instead of `i in 1:nrow(C)` to get the followers of the first 3 users only. The loop collects the followers in `D`. I looked at the twitter accounts of each of the first 3 users, compared that with `nrow(D)`

Comment: Sorry for asking many questions. But here is my code 
D <- c()
for(i in 1:3) {
  print(C[i,1])
  D <- rbind(D, get_followers(C[i,1], n= "all", page = "-1", parse = TRUE, as_double = FALSE, token = NULL))
}

Is this code giving you 2188? Because it is giving me 44525, which is wrong. So if this is working with you, the definitely I am doing something wrong

Comment: @HussainShehadeh yes, I copy pasted your code, it's exactly the same as mine, I ran it, and then `nrow(D)` gives 2190 now.

Comment: Fair enough, ill check what is going on. Thank you very much.

Comment: I uninstalled R then reinstalled it, and I ran the same code but still getting wrong results. Any idea why I may be getting wrong results? What can the issue be?

Comment: @HussainShehadeh Let's verify the values of `C`. Using your script, the first 3 values I have are "OneNaziq", "AzimRidzuan_", "pais_10". I suspect you have something else.

Comment: Yes I am having RaquishaW, x3smoker, angelinelejuez , These users have 221 , 391, and 1562 followers in total 2,172. After I run the same code I get 10258 results, which is wrong...

Comment: @HussainShehadeh I restarted R, and ran this: https://gist.github.com/janosgyerik/7dfa455a54d97c32a959464ea45cfe16, and it prints 2193 for me.

Comment: That makes sense, but I don't know why my laptop is showing 12,451. This is very weird, can it be something wrong with my system?

Comment: @HussainShehadeh I have no idea. But since you have a clear reproducer, you could perhaps ask a new question with this, using my Gist, the expected output (around 2193, will probably grow as the users keep getting new followers), and your actual output.